# The proper way to use Attribute Routing in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm working on a MVC5 project and trying to use Attribute Routing for organizing purposes, but it's  not working and I'm receiving a message saying that `"the resource can't be found"`.

The code in my Controller is:

```
  [Route("FrontEnd/IndexPage/Index")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

The subfolders under the Views folder are as the following:

- FrontEnd
- IndexPage
- Index.cshtml

Could you please advise me on the right routing approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view should be located at

```
Views\{controller}\{action}.cshtml
```

despite of any routing attributes. In your case folders `FrontEnd` and `IndexPage` are redundant and result should be the following

```
Views\{controller}\Index.cshtml
```

Comment: Thanks for your response,but how those two folders are redundant?I've created IndexPage folder inside FrontEnd folder and inside the IndexPage there is an Index.cshtml which is the view i wanna access.

Comment: @MOHAMMADALMASALMA I mean that your current folder structure is wrong, it should be like one from the answer

Answer (score 0):

Open RouteConfig file which is located in App_Start folder check attribute-based routing is enabled if not then just add,

routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

method just above routes.MapRoute

Refer this Link: 
[Attribute routing in asp.net mvc-5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've already included it , but i didn't work.